# Using a module or a feature in another package than where it is supposed to be used

Tags: perl

According to [Perl::Critic::Policy::Modules::RequireExplicitPackage](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::Critic::Policy::Modules::RequireExplicitPackage) :

> In general, the first statement of any Perl module or library should be a package statement. Otherwise, all the code that comes before the package statement is getting executed in the caller's package, and you have no idea who that is.

Now `Object::Pad` suggests to break this rule, see:
https://metacpan.org/pod/Object::Pad#File-Layout :

> Begin the file with a use Object::Pad line; ideally including a minimum-required version. This should be followed by the toplevel package and class declarations for the file.

I believe the same is suggested for the new `class` feature, see https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/pod/perlclass.pod, see e.g. the synopsis example there.

Is there any drawbacks to this approach? I guess any problems could be worked around by using the following file layout:

```
package MyClass; # ensure that Object::Pad is loaded within the `MyClass` package
use Object::Pad;
class MyClass;
...
```

instead of using this file layout

```
use Object::Pad;
class MyClass;
...
```

I am not sure why the documentation for Object::Pad suggests the latter file layout, or if it is even a problem. It would be great if someone could clarify this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load a module, you want to find the correct `import`. You want to find the correct subs loaded by the module. etc. The lack of `package` directive matching the `use` statement is a strong sign that there's a problem.

Obviously, this check isn't flawless. Like you said, the policy doesn't accommodate Object::Pad or the new `class` feature.

But, there are two things that uses the `package` directive directly. There's the policy in question, obviously. And there's CPAN. The indexer searches the source for `package PackageName;`. So including the `package` directive will help there.

And no, I don't see why Object::Pad would care from what package it was invoked, unless it has a check that prevents it from populating an existing package, a check you would already have discovered. Keep in mind that if you don't include the `package`, the code is executed in the namespace of the caller, which could be anything. So Object::Pad is obviously not picky about that.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I also found two related links discussing this issue here: https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Module-Metadata/issues/33 and https://github.com/Ovid/Cor/discussions/95

Comment: I asked on p5p if `class` was supported by the CPAN indexer earlier today. Apparently, there's a [patch](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/Module-Metadata/pull/34) that's been waiting for quite some time. In fact, it's associated with the very issue you mentioned. And it's definitely getting to be the time it's applied.

Answer (score 4):

This quote is not strictly true:

> In general, the first statement of any Perl module or library should be a package statement. Otherwise, all the code that comes before the package statement is getting executed in the caller's package, and you have no idea who that is.

In particular, the second sentence is not always correct. For example, consider this module:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package My::Module;

...;

1;
```

The `use strict` and `use warnings` are applied to your module and not to the caller. This is because they have a *lexical effect*.

Object::Pad similarly has lexical effect, so this is fine:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Object::Pad;

class My::Module;

...;

1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't get too wrapped up with the advice from *Perl Best Practices* or `Perl::Critic`. Some of the advice obviates beginner traps that will lead to future problems, and other advice merely enforces consistency across a code base. People have put more weight on these things than they really merit, and they don't hold up for all situations. See, for example, [Damian's much more tempered responses](https://66.39.102.137/Interviews/damian-bpp-20050622.html) in my interview with him.

Something like `Object::Pad`, which screws around with Perl, can't be bound by the everyday rules of Perl. When it comes to things like that, pay more attention to the particular advice than the general advice. `Object::Pad` knows better about how it should be used.

Looking at all of my modules, I mostly put the `package` statement on the first line, but here are some other things that show up: `use v5.10` (or some version), `use utf8`, or `use strict` (which after v5.12 is part of the version bundle).

Answer (score 1):

`Object::Pad` is more a pragma, or rather an experiment on pragmata.

`strict` and `warnings` are other examples of pragmata. They are usually written in lower-case to be better distinguished from usual modules, so your confusion is understandable.

see https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpragma

> A pragma is a module which influences some aspect of the compile time or run time behaviour of Perl, such as strict or warnings. With Perl 5.10 you are no longer limited to the built in pragmata; you can now create user pragmata that modify the behaviour of user functions within a lexical scope.

"Normal" modules - i.e. those exporting functions, should always follow the (or a) package declaration, because exports are limited to the caller's namespace and aren't visible outside.

Object::Pad is not normal, it's injecting new experimental keywords into the language.